# Add Photoshop Object Model to Extendscript Toolkit

Tags: javascript, adobe, photoshop, extendscript

How can I include the Photoshop Object Model in the Extendscript Toolkit?

Other CC products' Object Models appear to have been included by default, however I cannot figure out how to add Photoshop (and later, Lightroom) Object Models.

[image: Other Object Models appear by defualt]

Comment: It worked for my previous version (CC2015.5), but after installing the most recent CC2018 (v19.1.5), that did not appear as a separate choice. Seems Adobe broke something. The script engine help for the most recent Illustrator *does* appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an installation issue. There is a thread in the adobe community: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2549963. I double checkt it and it works.

Solution is: **Remove** and **reinstall** the extended script toolkit and photoshop. Settings of both tools can be kept.